# Given set $A = \{\{1,2\}, 3\}$, the powerset of $A$ is then $\{\emptyset, \{\{1,2\}\}, \{3\}, \{\{1,2\}, 3\}\}$ , what is $P(A)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set $A = \{\{1,2\}, 3\}$, the powerset of $A$ is then $\{\emptyset, \{\{1,2\}\}, \{3\}, \{\{1,2\}, 3\}\}$. So is $\{1,2\}$ an element of the powerset of $A$?

Comment: Do not "*flatten*" the elements in your mind.  Although $\{\{1,2\}\}$ may be an element, $\{1,2\}$ is not.  These are not the same object.  The first is a one element set.  The second is a two-element set.  While it may be possible for something to both be an element of and a subset of a set simultaneously, most of the time that will not be the case and if both were true it would have been for completely different reasons.

Comment: For example, with $B=\{\color{red}{\{1,2\}},\color{blue}{1,2}\}$, you will have that $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of $B$ thanks to the part of $B$ colored blue while $\{1,2\}$ is an element of $B$ thanks to the part of $B$ colored red.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = \{1, 2\}$, so that $A = \{X, 3\}$ and $P(A) = \{\emptyset, \{X\}, \{3\}, \{X, 3\}\}$. Based on what you understand of sets and their elements, is $X \in P(A)$?

Comment: No? because P(A) does not have the element X?

Comment: And so does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you.